# Where is Properties Files node in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mybatis

I read a guideline which is about how to connect mysql with eclipse.The step is add a new properites files with eclipse tree node named Properties Fiels.But i can not find it.
Is it a old version?

[image]

Comment: Show us *your* version.

Comment: my eclipse version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a). I don't know the shortcut version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create file using `File` under `General` folder.

[image]

Give it a name that ends with `.properties`.